# How do I find the powerset of $A\cap B$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$A = \{0,1\}$

$B = \{1,2\}$

My Working :

$P(A\cap B)= P(\{\varnothing, \{1\}\}) = \{\varnothing,\{1\},\{\varnothing,\{1\}\}\}$

But the correct answer is $P(A\cap B)= \{\varnothing , \{1\}\}$.

Comment: $A\cap B=\{1\}$.

Comment: The empty set is a odd ball. We say $\emptyset \subset A$ for all $A$ but that does NOT mean $\emptyset \in A$ for all $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intersection of $A$ and $B$ is simply $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$, which has only $\lbrace \rbrace$ and $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ as subsets, and so the power set is $\lbrace\lbrace \rbrace, \lbrace 1\rbrace \rbrace$. The empty set is a *subset* of $A$ and $B$, but it is not a *member* of either set. Therefore, the empty set is not a member of $A \cap B$. Similarly, $\lbrace 1\rbrace$ is a subset of, not a member of, $A$ and $B$, so it is not a member of the intersection.

Answer (score -1):

$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cap P(B)$ as any subset of $A\cap B$ has to be a subset of both $A$ and $B$, and the converse is trivial.